# Intellij IDEA - Unable to Open Cloud Files showing in orange text

Tags: intellij-idea

**Context:**

Need some advice from the Community as we are experiencing something strange since upgrading Intellij IDEA Ultimate above 2022.3.

**Problem:**

When storing a project on OneDrive (or similar cloud storage) when a user comes to open the project on a **managed machine**, the project opens but all files are showing in orange and as non-classes:

[image: file structure error]

Users are then **unable to open the files** by double clicking them. The only way we have found is by dragging them into the workspace, but the files remain in this "orange" state.

There is no VCS integration on these projects, so it is unlike when files are red, blue, green etc showing VCS status.

---

**Question:**

How do we solve this issue and what is the root cause?

---

**Steps Taken:**

I've tried opening the project on a **personal machine** from the same cloud storage directory and the same version of Intellij IDEA and it works as expected:

[image: file structure expected]

I am at a loss as to why this is happening, and I cannot find any existing documentation to explain the orange colouring. This behaviour **DID NOT** happen in 2022.2 and below.

**N.B.** We have a non-negotiable that requires our project files to be stored on OneDrive as these are shared and backed up in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Disable OneDrive **Files On-Demand** option so that they are always available on disk:

[image: Files On-Demand]

Comment: Unfortunately, that option is managed and locked to on by MDM :(